# is it ok to check normality for individual groups seperated by within-subject variables in a mixed model rather than the entire dataset?

Tags: mixed-model, normality-assumption

Wikipedia mentions that it is crucial to ensure normality for within-subject variables in a mixed model. I am interpreting this as I should check normality for my within-subject variables and not between subject variables.

I have 4 variables: 2 within-subject and 2 between-subjects. Within-subject variables: v1: 2 levels; v2: 3 levels. Between-subject variables: v3: 2 levels; v4: 2 levels. When I test normality for my within-subject variables, I get total 6 groups/columns, each with a sample size of 49. All 6 are normal. However, when I check the normality for the entire data set (i.e, without separating in the 2x3 groups), the data is not normal.

What do you guys think is the correct way of doing this normality testing? Also, which other transformations can be used for positive skewed data other than sqrt, Lg10, boxcox and inverse? What if these transformations do not make the data normal according to Shepiro-Wilk test? My only option is to use parametric test in that case?

Thank you in advance and as always, please let me know if I am not clear in any portion. PS: I will be running either a GLM repeated measure or MIXED in SPSS on this data.

EDIT: When I try to correct normality for the big dataset (294 values), it becomes almost impossible to correct normality for one of the response variables. This makes me want to stick to checking normality for 6 groups individually. But I would really like to know if it is ok to check normality like this. Help!

Comment: Why can't you check for normality with 294 values?

Comment: I certainly can. When I do check normality for 294 values, it is nonnormal and I tried several transformations (sqrt, log10, natural log, inverse). The data does not become normal after any of these transformations. Whereas, the normality is easy to gain across the  groups. I don't know what's the correct way.